# Non-Linear Minimization (nlm) in R with error: incorrect number of dimensions

Tags: r, optimization, nlm

I have this code where it calculates the negative binomial distribution, 
with parameters:

```
ce <- c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
ce <- as.integer(ce)
comp <- c(257, 155, 64, 17, 5, 2)
comp <- as.integer(comp)
data.cells <- data.frame(ce, comp)

params <- c(5, 1.5) # vector of 2 params, x and κ. 
dat <- data.cells
```

And the function:

```
negbinll <- function(dat,params) {
  if (missing(dat)||missing(params)) {
    print('Plese add values for the model')
  } else if (params[1]<0||params[2]<0) {
    print('Plese make sure your parameters are >0')
  } else {
    p <- params[1]/(params[1]+params[2])
    N <- params[1] + dat[,1] - 1
    log.l <- sum(dat[2]*dnbinom(dat[,1], size = N, prob = p, log = TRUE))
    return(log.l)
  }
}
```

Now, the result from this code is

```
> negbinll(dat, params)
[1] -591.024
```

The next step is to use `nlm` (Non-Linear Minimization) to find the maximum likelihood estimates of x and κ, assume params = (x, κ)

```
nlm(negbinll, dat, p = params)
Error in dat[, 1] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

But, if I change in the initial function the dat[,1] to dat[1] I get an error:
 Non-numeric argument to mathematical function

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Looking at the `?nlm` help page, I don't see a data argument. Also think the parameter list would basically throw away any values  if it were not named, because there is no positional matching after `(f, p, ...)`

Comment: You just gave me an idea, let me try something. The data argument supposed to be dat followed by params. I put them in the nlm on the same sequence to match the negbinll

Comment: Ok, I feel completely stupid. I thought that no matter the `(f, p, ...)` sequence the function would work. Apparently, I should have constructed the first code like that: `negbinll <- function(params, dat)` instead of dat then params

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dat` and `params` values are matched incorrectly inside `negbinll` function. To debug it, put `browser()` inside the `negbinll` function and call the `nlm` line of code. Inside the debug mode, you can print the values of `dat` and `params` and see that they are not matched properly.

Note: after debugging, remove the `browser()` command from `negbinll` function

```
negbinll <- function(dat,params) {
  browser()
  if (missing(dat)||missing(params)) {
    print('Plese add values for the model')
  } else if (params[1]<0||params[2]<0) {
    print('Plese make sure your parameters are >0')
  } else {
    p <- params[1]/(params[1]+params[2])
    N <- params[1] + dat[,1] - 1
    log.l <- sum( dat[2] *dnbinom(dat[,1], size = N, prob = p, log = TRUE))
    return(log.l)
  }
}

Browse[2]> params
# ce comp
# 1  0  257
# 2  1  155
# 3  2   64
# 4  3   17
# 5  4    5
# 6  5    2
Browse[2]> dat
# [1] 5.0 1.5
```

Comment: Thanks @Sathish, I just found out too. Check my reply on the comments bellow the question!